# Finding Union of LatLngBounds in Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to find the Union of two [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) in Google Maps for Android. I can't seem to locate a method in the documentation to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add one of your ``` LatLngBounds``northeast ``` and `southwest` coordinates to the other `LatLngBounds` using the [`including` method](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html#including(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng)):

```
LatLngBounds bounds1 = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(8.2,48.2), new LatLng(8.1,47.2));
LatLngBounds bounds2 = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(8.1,48.1), new LatLng(8.0,47.1));

// Expand bounds1 to include bounds2
bounds1.including(bounds2.northeast);
bounds1.including(bounds2.southwest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Antonio's answer displayed only `bounds1` for me. What worked was the use of `LatLng.Builder`:

```
LatLngBounds bounds1 = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(8.2,48.2), new LatLng(8.1,47.2));
LatLngBounds bounds2 = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(8.1,48.1), new LatLng(8.0,47.1));
LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

boundsBuilder.include(bounds1.northeast);
boundsBuilder.include(bounds1.southwest);

boundsBuilder.include(bounds2.northeast);
boundsBuilder.include(bounds2.southwest);

LatLngBounds unionBounds = boundsBuilder.build();
```